# Why isn't the bar chart drawn here?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, data-visualization

I want to make bar chart using d3 and Angular(in VSCode), But it doesn't work.
I think there is a problem with the x-axis. Can you help me?
Only the y-axis is drawn and there is no additional response.
I'm still hesitating on this part, and I keep tweaking the code and there's no progress.

Thank you!

//elect.tsv
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibaeW.png)

```
//template.component.ts

import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

interface ILayoutInfo {
  marginTop: number;
  marginRight: number;
  marginBottom: number;
  marginLeft: number;
  height: number;
  width: number;
  boundedHeight?: number;
  boundedWidth?: number;
}

interface IData {
  idx : string;
  elect : string;
  fre : number;
  decrease : number;
  increase : number;
  nochange : number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.scss']
})

export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  layout: ILayoutInfo;

  @ViewChild('rootSvg') svgRoot!: ElementRef;
  constructor() {
    this.layout = {
      marginTop: 20, marginRight: 20, marginBottom: 30, marginLeft: 40,
      height: 500, width: 960
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    d3.tsv('./assets/elect.tsv').then((d: any) => {
      d.decrease = +d.decrease;
      d.idx = +d.idx;
      return d;
    }).then((data: IData[]) => {
      this.render(data);
    });
  }

  render(data: IData[]): void {
    
    const svg = d3.select(this.svgRoot.nativeElement)
      .attr('width', this.layout.width)
      .attr('height', this.layout.height);

    const width = +svg.attr('width') - this.layout.marginLeft - this.layout.marginRight,
      height = +svg.attr('height') - this.layout.marginTop - this.layout.marginBottom;

    const x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
    console.log(x);

    const g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.layout.marginLeft + ',' + this.layout.marginTop + ')');

    x.domain(data.map(d => d.idx));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, (d: IData) => d.decrease) as number]);

    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10))
      .select('path')
      .style('display', 'none');

    g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10))
      .append('text')
      .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
      .attr('y', 6)
      .attr('dy', '0.71em')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
      .text('Decrease');
      
    g.selectAll('bar')
      .data(data)
      .enter().append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', (d: IData) => x(d.idx) as number)
      .attr('y', (d: IData) => y(d.decrease))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', function(d) { return height - y(d.decrease); })
      .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
      .on('mouseover', function (this) {
        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'brown');
      })
      .on('mouseout', function (this) {
        d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'steelblue');
      });

  }
}
```

```
//template.component.html

<div class="container">
    <svg #rootSvg class="chart"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your x-axis has the a `style` attribute of `display: none` applied, so it will not be visible.

```
g.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10))
      // remove the lines below --> 
      // .select('path')  
      // .style('display', 'none');
```

Remove those lines and you should be back on track.

Comment: Thank you! x-axis display, but the bar did not display yet. Can you help this problem?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproduction of your code in Angular on Codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io

Comment: `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements`

Comment: Use the dev tools and log the file you're reading into the console and it's immediately clear that the file `assets/elect.tsv` does not exist. 

Without data, the chart can't be rendered because there is no data to bind to any DOM elements.

Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/wlCvUNS